# How to add text in between two lines adaptively using matplotlib?

Tags: python, matplotlib, text, fill, plot-annotations

How to add text in between two lines adaptively like this fig below?
[image]

of course, you can use `ax.annotate`. However, when the line changes, you have to find once again the coordinate to put the text...

I know there is  `fill_between` function for hatched zone, but how could I add text in best location adaptively according to the line given.

Below are my sample code for easy understanding

```
from pylab import *

x=array([0,1])
yc=array([0.55,0.48])


yhc=array([0.55,0.68])

yagg=array([0.45,0.48])

plot(x,yc,'k-',linewidth=1.5)
plot(x,yhc,'k-',linewidth=1.5)
plot(x,yagg,'k-',linewidth=1.5)

xticks(fontsize = 22)
yticks(fontsize = 22)
ylim(0,1)

savefig('vp.png', transparent=True,bbox_inches='tight')
```

[image]

Comment: From the first figure it looks to me that the center of gravity of the triangles and quadrilaterals would be nice center points for annotated texts.

Comment: `annotate` will also take a position in data coordinates.

Comment: Thank you, guys, you definitely offer an alternative solution